# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS on attempt to install and run gluonfx HelloFX

Tags: android, maven, javafx, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

I am working through the steps starting at this point in the Gluon-Mobile documentation.
https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android_sample

The following steps succeeded, and in each case, the expected files were created. I was very pleased to see the .apk file in the expected location after the package command was run.

- mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:compile
- mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:link
- mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:package

When I ran the command to install and run on my device

- mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:install gluonfx:nativerun

I received the following exception message:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries
```

I see that my device was correctly identified (LM X210VPP).
There is a warning prior, is this related to the failure?

```
No version of NDK matched the required version 21.1.6352462.
```

Following is a larger excerpt from the log file. If more is needed, please let me know!

```
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:18 PDT 2021][FINE] Start process install-task...
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:19 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:20 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:27 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] 
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] WARNING: No version of NDK matched the required version 21.1.6352462. Versions available locally: 
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] No version of NDK matched the required version 21.1.6352462. Versions available locally: 
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] 
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:28 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:30 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] 
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:30 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:installDebug
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:30 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] [adb]: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:30 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] [adb]: * daemon started successfully
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:31 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'LM-X210VPP - 7.1.2' for app:debug
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:35 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] Unable to install /home/phil/Projects/metronome/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:35 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
[Tue Sep 21 17:42:35 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB]
```

Does this mean that my particular device is not covered? I found [this page from Android about ABIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis), and am trying to figure out how my device relates. UPDATE: phone has armeabi-v7z instruction set. This seems to me like it should be supported, as it is listed in the page I linked just above of Android ABIs. I'm back to wondering if there is something awry with the NDK that I should be paying more attention to.

**EDIT (10/3/21), FOLLOWING UP ON INSTRUCTIONS GIVEN IN COMMENTS**

I am experiencing the same error with a phone that has a 64-bit CPU and instruction set:

From [GSM Arena, Motorola Moto G Fast](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g_fast-10286.php)

```
OS:     Android 10
Chipset:    Qualcomm SM6125 Snapdragon 665 (11 nm)
CPU:    Octa-core (4x2.0 GHz Kryo 260 Gold & 4x1.8 GHz Kryo 260 Silver)
```

From Qualcomm [Snapdragon 665](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-665-mobile-platform)

```
CPU    CPU Clock Speed: Up to 2.0 GHz
             CPU Cores: Qualcomm® Kryo™ 260 CPU, Octa-core CPU
      CPU Architecture: 64-bit
```

Checking the hardware info on the phone using the Droid Hardware Info tool:

```
CPU Architecture: AArch64 processor rev 2(aarch64)
           Board: rav
Instruction Sets: arm64-v8a
```

From the log

```
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:27 PDT 2021][INFO] ==================== INSTALL TASK ====================
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:27 PDT 2021][FINE] PB Command for install-task: /home/phil/Projects/metronome/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/gradlew -p /home/phil/Projects/metronome/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project installDebug
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:27 PDT 2021][FINE] Start process install-task...
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:29 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:30 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:38 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] 
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] WARNING: No version of NDK matched the required version 21.1.6352462. Versions available locally: 
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] No version of NDK matched the required version 21.1.6352462. Versions available locally: 
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] 
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:39 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:41 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] 
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:41 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] > Task :app:installDebug
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:41 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] [adb]: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:41 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] [adb]: * daemon started successfully
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:41 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'LGL455DL - 9' for app:debug
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:44 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] Unable to install /home/phil/Projects/metronome/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[Fri Oct 01 17:15:44 PDT 2021][FINE] [SUB] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: If you check the docs at https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_platforms, the `Platform architecture matrix for Native Image` shows that only 64 bits platforms are supported (x64 on desktop, AArch64 on mobile). Unfortunately, your phone has `armeabi-v7z` (32 bits) which is not the expected one `arm64-v8a` (64 bits). The reason for this if the lack of 32 bits support from GraalVM (see https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1329).

Comment: I have followed up with a 64-bit phone and am getting the same error message. The device, in an earlier test, was detected by AndroidStudio and successfully ran a "MyFirstApp" tutorial from the developer.android.com site. What else might be the problem?

Comment: Plug your phone to your computer and run from a terminal `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi `, what do you get? Note: `adb` is a tool under `<Android SDK path>/platform-tools`.

Comment: Also you can run `adb shell`, and then when you get the phone's prompt, run `uname-a`.  I get `arm64-v8a` for cpu.abi and `Linux localhost 3.18.137-g72a... 2019 aarch64` for uname.

Comment: Sorry, try `uname -a`

Comment: Linux localhost 4.14.117-perf+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 24 06:37:26 CDT 2020 aarch64

Comment: Ok, there shouldn’t be a reason why the 64 bits app can’t be installed now. You can try manually with `adb install <path to your apk>`. Post the output if that fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237766/discussion-between-phil-freihofner-and-jose-pereda).